# php mysql remove numbered key's from fetched array row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to do a mysql fetch but it keeps adding numbered and labeled keys to the array. I want it to record only the labeled names and data in the array.

Am I using the wrong mysql call?

```
global $con,$mysqldb;
$sql="SHOW FIELDS FROM ".$dbtable;
$tr = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$tl = mysqli_fetch_array($tr);
$tl = mysqli_fetch_array($tr);

$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$mysqldb.".".$dbtable." ORDER BY ".$tl['Field']." LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $table[$row[1]] = $row;
}

foreach($table as $item => $data){
    foreach(array_keys($data) as $pointer => $field) {
        echo"pointer=".$pointer."\t";
        echo"field=".$field."\n";
        echo "data=".$data[$field]."\n";
    }
}
```

### reults

```
pointer=0       field=0 data=3823
pointer=1       field=PID       data=3823
pointer=2       field=1 data=AA
pointer=3       field=symbol    data=AA
pointer=4       field=2 data=1
pointer=5       field=value   data=1
```

I want to omit 0, 2, & 4 from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP.net manual for the [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) function.

You'll see there's an option called `resulttype` that will accept 1 of 3 values - `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, or `MYSQLI_BOTH` the default.

Using `MYSQLI_ASSOC` will remove the numbered keys.

Or check [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much. Saved me hours of headaches.

Comment: As soon as it will let me. You responded so fast the system won't let me select it as the correct answer yet.

Comment: This is a very big help. Not only has cleaned up the array, It has freed up half the memory too. Very helpful when working with over 10,000 records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to thebluefox for a speedy response.
I replaced the fetch with:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

And now the results are being recorded as they should.